# Spring Data for Apache Cassandra converts java.time.LocalDateTime to UTC

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, timezone, spring-data-cassandra

I am attempting to persist a `java.time.LocalDateTime` object in my Cassandra database and keep it timezone agnostic. I am using Spring Data Cassandra to do this.

The problem is that somewhere along the line, something is treating these `LocalDateTime` objects as if they are in the timezone of my server, and offsetting them to UTC time when it stores them in the database.

Is this a bug or a feature?  Can I work around it in some way?

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
    basePackages = "my.base.package")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration{

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "keyspacename";
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster =
            new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(9142);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping()
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }
}
```

Booking record I wish to persist:

```
@Table("booking")
public class BookingRecord {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
        ordinal = 0,
        type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED
    )
    private UUID bookingId = null;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(
        ordinal = 1,
        type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED,
        ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING
    )
    private LocalDateTime startTime = null;
    ...
}
```

Simple Repository Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface BookingRepository extends CassandraRepository<BookingRecord> { }
```

Save Call:

```
...

@Autowired
BookingRepository bookingRepository;

...

public void saveBookingRecord(BookingRecord bookingRecord) {
    bookingRepository.save(bookingRecord);
}
```

Here is the string used to populate the starttime in BookingRecord:

```
"startTime": "2017-06-10T10:00:00Z"
```

And here is the output from cqlsh after the timestamp has been persisted:

```
cqlsh:keyspacename> select * from booking ;

 bookingid                            | starttime               
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------
 8b640c30-4c94-11e7-898b-6dab708ec5b4 | 2017-06-10 15:00:00.000000+0000
```

Comment: why don't you use `Locale` while setting timeformat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do actually want to use `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` in my project, rather than `java.util.Date`, since they are newer and have more attractive functionality.

After much searching I have found a workaround.

First, you must create custom implementations of Spring's `Converter` interface as follows:

One for `Date` to `LocalDateTime`:

```
public class DateToLocalDateTime implements Converter<Date, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(Date source) {
        return source == null ? null : LocalDateTime.ofInstant(source.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }

}
```

And one for `LocalDateTime` to `Date`:

```
public class LocalDateTimeToDate implements Converter<LocalDateTime, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(LocalDateTime source) {
        return source == null ? null : Date.from(source.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    }

}
```

Finally, you must override the `customConversions` method in `CassandraConfig` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "my.base.package")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration{

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "keyspacename";
    }

    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter> converters = new ArrayList<>();

        converters.add(new DateToLocalDateTime());
        converters.add(new LocalDateTimeToDate());

        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster =
            new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(9142);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping()
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }
}
```

Thanks to mp911de for putting me in the ballpark of where to look for the solution!

Answer (score 9):

Cassandra stores a Date (`timestamp`) as [milliseconds since epoch without a specific timezone information](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html). Timezone data is handled in the layers above Cassandra.

`LocalDate`/`LocalDateTime` represent a point in time relative to your local time. Before the date/time can be saved, it needs to be enhanced with a timezone to calculate the generic representation, which can be saved.

Spring Data uses your system-default timezone ([`Date.from(source.atZone(systemDefault()).toInstant())`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters.java#L107)).

If you need timezone precision and want to omit any implicit timezone conversions, use `java.util.Date` directly which corresponds with Cassandra's (well, it's the Datastax Driver to be precise) storage format representation.

Comment: Thanks!  that did the trick.  I was under the impression that the 'Local' in LocalDate and LocalDateTime meant the values were timezone agnostic, but it sounds like the opposite is true.

Comment: the source of my confusion- from the javadoc for LocalDateTime

    "A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30."

Comment: Minor correction: Cassandra stores timestamp in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: It seems when persist by spring data, the localdatetime will always be convert to UTC according to your system timezone. Who knows how to cheat spring data your timezone is "UTC'？